# WordML language auto detedt

Tags: ms-word, wordml, wordprocessingml

I'm creating a wordml document, that is typically not in english. Word marks all words as mis-spelled. I know about the `<w:lang>` tag, but the trouble is that i don't know the language while creating. Is there a way to instruct word to auto detect the language? Or at least to prevent the spelling check? Or maybe a simple way to detect the language in code?
Thanks a lot, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prevent spelling check by adding  to the run parameters of each run (e.g.  )